# how to make carousal animation in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-animations

[image]

Hello all i need to make carousal same as image. horizontal circular carousal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party tool achieve this kind of functionality.

[CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) open source UI components
for iOS and OS X.

[CFCoverFlowView](https://github.com/c0ming/CFCoverFlowView) and [YRCoverFlowLayout](https://github.com/solomidSF/YRCoverFlowLayout)  two controls may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check its almost same.
https://github.com/lukagabric/LGLinearFlow